# Bash how to replace comment backslash with nothing

Tags: regex, bash

I have a strign in bash with the following format:

// comment.

I want to obtain a new variable with comment alone (no backslash) and I don't want to depend on the // begin the first two characters in the string. How can I do this?

I have tried this:

```
  nline=${line/%/////}
  echo $nline
```

To use string substitution but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "depend on the // begin the first two characters"? Please rewrite your question a little more carefully. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want the `#` substitution?

```
$ a='// this is a comment'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a#// }"
this is a comment
$ a='not a comment'
$ printf "%s\n" "${a#// }"
not a comment
```

And as SergA pointed out, a little better patterns for our variable extraction can save us the need for the sed solution below:

```
$ a="first //a comment"
$ printf "%s" "${a##*//}"
```

If you just want to get the comment part of a line anywhere it is you could use `sed` like so:

```
$ a="first //a comment"
$ printf "%s\n" "$a" | sed -e 's,^.*// \?,,'
a comment
```

which of course you could store in another variable:

```
nline=$(printf "%s" "$a" | sed -e 's,^.*// \?,,')
```

(note also that I remved the `\n` from the `printf`)

Comment: Instead using `sed` you can use variable mangling in bash: get all before comment - `echo ${a%%//*}`, get comment - `echo ${a#*//}`

Comment: @SergA Thanks for the suggestion, I incorporated it (though your comment used the same example for both before and after the comment)

Answer (score 0):

Remove first two characters:

```
echo ${nline:2}
```

Comment: OP indicated that assuming the `//` were the first two characters was not desirable.

Comment: Right, it is *explicitly* not an answer to the question the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

`%` matches the end of the string. `#` matches the beginning of the string.

Since you said you wanted neither of those you don't want either `%` or `#` in there.

Also you need to escape `/` in a `/`-delimited pattern.

```
nline=${line/\/\/}
echo "$nline"
```

This will remove the first `//` from the string no matter where it is or what comes before it. So `foo // comment` will become `foo  comment`, etc.

If you want to also remove any surrounding spaces from the `//` string then you need to do a bit more work and can't so easily use string substitution for it.